# -fx-background-image doesn't work in Gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I need to set background-image for my GridPane and there was no problem until I started use Gradle. Now  my code doesn't work and I don't know what is wrong because it works in javaFX project but does not in Gradle project

```
this.setStyle(
           "-fx-background-image: url('../resources/sprites/Field.png');" +
                   "-fx-background-size: cover;"
   );
```

Comment: As your image appears to be a resource, try using `url('/sprites/Field.png')`. See the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeurl) for more information.

Comment: I tried url('/sprites/Field.png') but it doesn't work too. Thanks for the link btw